# How do I change the Homepage URL for an existing GitHub project?

Tags: github

While creating a new project on GitHub, there is a field called Homepage URL (optional). How do I change the Homepage URL for an existing project?

Answer (score 2):

When you hover the mouse over the description and homepage url at the top, you will get a `Edit` button. click on it and change.

[image]